# Basic integration question: integration bounds for $\iint x^2y^2 \ dx\,dy$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I have the integral
$$\iint x^2y^2 \ dx\,dy$$
but I am meant to evaluate it at the limits $0<y<1$ and $-2y<x<2y$. I am wondering what terminals of integration I should put in for $x$. Do I evaluate between $x=-2y$ and $x=2y$ or between $x=-2$ and $x=2$?

Comment: They'll be $x=-2y$ and $x=2y$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$
\iint x^2y^2\,dx\,dy=\int_0^1y^2\left[\int_{-2y}^{2y}x^2\,dx\right]\,dy=\int_0^1y^2\left[\frac{x^3}{3}\right]_{-2y}^{2y}\,dy=\int_0^1\frac{16}{3}y^5\,dy=\frac{16}{3\cdot6}y^6\Big|_0^1=\frac89.
$$

Comment: Some mistakes in your answer - you accidentally dropped the $y^2$ between the second and third form, and even ignoring that, you wrote $y^3$ instead of $y^4$ upon evaluating the outer integral.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If we swapped the $dx$ and $dy$ around after the integrand, we would get a different answer wouldn't we?

Comment: @J.Finnegan Using [Fubini's theorem](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/DIGeneralRegion.aspx), you *can* swap the $dx$ and $dy$ -- but you've also got to reparametrize your region so that your bounds of integration are correct.

Answer (score 4):

First evaluate
$$\int_{-2y}^{2y}x^2y^2dx$$
treating $y$ as some contant with a value between $0$ and $1$.

You will get an expresion on $y$, which now you should integrate between $0$ and $1$, say
$$\int_0^1 f(y)dy$$